# disable html form submit button using js form verifyer

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to make a simple js form verifier using boolean values which checks if the inputs from html are correct and enables the submit button if fields are correct or disables it if not. It disables the submit button but when data is entered correctly it does not re enable the submit button.

```
    var validemail = false ;
    var validpassword = false ;
    var validusername = false ;
    var validage = false ;

    function verifyemail()
{
    var email = document.getElementById("signupemail").value ;
    var error = document.getElementById("signupemailerrors") ;
    var emailregex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/ ;

    if(email.length < 254){
    if( email.length > 0 ){
        if(email.match(emailregex)){
            error.innerHTML = "";
            validemail = true ;
        }
        else
        {
            error.innerHTML = "Invalid email address.";
            validemail = false ;
        }

    }else

    {
        error.innerHTML = "Please fill in." ;
        validemail = false ;
    }
} else
{
    error.innerHTML = "Maximum length exceeded.";
    validemail= false ;
}
}

function verifypassword(){
    var password = document.getElementById("signuppassword").value;
    var passworderror= document.getElementById("signuppassworderrors") ;
    if (password.length < 254){
    if(password.length > 7){
    passworderror.innerHTML = "";
    validpassword = true ;

    }
        else if(password.length == 0)
    {
        passworderror.innerHTML = "Please fill in.";
        validpassword = false ;
    }
    else
    {
        passworderror.innerHTML = "At least 8 characters required.";
        validpassword = false ;
    }
}
    else
    {
        passworderror.innerHTML = "Maximum length exceeded.";
        validpassword = false ;
    }
}

function verifyusername(){
    var username = document.getElementById("signupusername").value ;
    var usernamerror = document.getElementById("signupusernameerrors") ;

    if (username.length == 0)
    {
        usernamerror.innerHTML = "Please fill in.";
        validusername = false;
    }
    else if (username.length > 50)
    {
        usernamerror.innerHTML = "Maximum length exceeded.";
        validusername = false;
    }
    else
    {
        usernamerror.innerHTML = "";
        validusername = true;
    }
}

function verifyage(){
    var age = document.getElementById("signupage").value ;
    var ageerror = document.getElementById("signupageerrors") ;
    var ageregex = /^\d+$/;

    if(age.length == 0){
        ageerror.innerHTML = "Please fill this field";
        validage = false;
    }
    else
    {
    if (age.match(ageregex)){
        if (age == 0){
        ageerror.innerHTML = "Please provide your real age." ;
        validage = false;
        }
        else if(age > 130){
        ageerror.innerHTML = "Please provide your real age." ;
        validage = false;
        }
        else
        {
        ageerror.innerHTML = "" ;
        validage = true;
        }

    }else
    {
        ageerror.innerHTML = "Only numbers allowed."
        validage = false;
    }
}
}


function verifysubmit(){
    verifyage();
    verifyemail();
    verifypassword();
    verifyusername();
    if (validage == true && validemail == true && validpassword == true && validusername == true)
    {
     document.getElementById("signupformsubmit").disabled = false ;
    }
else{
    document.getElementById("signupformsubmit").disabled = true ;
}
}
```

Comment: In your verifysubmit function, only test one condition at a time to find out which field is returning false. `if (validage == true && validemail == true && validpassword == true && validusername == true)`

Comment: by html [onmouseover="verifysubmit()"]

Comment: can you please share the html of your form ? seems to be working when I tried.

Comment: here is the code with html http://jsfiddle.net/feherlevente/FGVma/31/  hope this helps.

Comment: Just a side note.  NEVER rely on JavaScript verifiers.  You MUST have a proper server side verifier to ensure people are not inserting attacks into your system.  IMO you're spending too much time on this.

Comment: I just want to make the js verifiers to interact with the user via interface. To send error messages and to change some things depending on the input. But on the server side I will use php to verify the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE tested and worked code:**

```
<input type="text" id="signupemail" oninput="verifyemail();">
<div id="signupemailerrors"></div>
<input type="password" id="signuppassword" oninput="verifypassword();">
<div id="signuppassworderrors"></div>
<input type="text" id="signupage" oninput="verifyage();">
<div id="signupageerrors"></div>
<input type="text" id="signupusername" oninput="verifyusername();">
<div id="signupusernameerrors"></div>
<input type="submit" id="signupformsubmit">

<script>

    var validemail = false ;
    var validpassword = false ;
    var validusername = false ;
    var validage = false ;

    verifysubmit();

    function verifyemail(){

        var email = document.getElementById("signupemail").value;
        var emailerror = document.getElementById("signupemailerrors");
        var emailregex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

        validemail = true;
        emailerror.innerHTML = "";

        if (email.length == 0) {
            emailerror.innerHTML = "Please fill in." ;
            validemail = false ;
        } else if (email.length > 254) {
            emailerror.innerHTML = "Maximum length exceeded.";
            validemail= false ;
        } else if (!email.match(emailregex)) {
            emailerror.innerHTML = "Invalid email address.";
            validemail = false ;
        }

        verifysubmit();

    }


    function verifypassword(){

        var password = document.getElementById("signuppassword").value;
        var passworderror= document.getElementById("signuppassworderrors") ;

        validpassword = true;
        passworderror.innerHTML = "";

        if (password.length == 0) {
            passworderror.innerHTML = "Please fill in." ;
            validpassword = false ;
        } else if (password.length < 8) {
            passworderror.innerHTML = "At least 8 characters required.";
            validpassword= false ;
        } else if (password.length > 254) {
            passworderror.innerHTML = "Maximum length exceeded.";
            validpassword= false ;
        } 

        verifysubmit();

    }


    function verifyusername(){

        var username = document.getElementById("signupusername").value;
        var usernamerror= document.getElementById("signupusernameerrors") ;

        validusername = true;
        usernamerror.innerHTML = "";

        if (username.length == 0) {
            usernamerror.innerHTML = "Please fill in." ;
            validusername = false ;
        } else if (username.length < 3) {
            usernamerror.innerHTML = "At least 3 characters required.";
            validusername= false ;
        } else if (username.length > 50) {
            usernamerror.innerHTML = "Maximum length exceeded.";
            validusername= false ;
        } 

        verifysubmit();

    }


    function verifyage(){

        var age = document.getElementById("signupage").value ;
        var ageerror = document.getElementById("signupageerrors") ;
        var ageregex = /^\d+$/;

        validage = true;
        ageerror.innerHTML = "";

        if (age.length == 0){
            ageerror.innerHTML = "Please fill this field";
            validage = false;
        } else if ((age > 130) || (age == 0)) {
            ageerror.innerHTML = "Please provide your real age." ;
            validage = false;
        } else if (!age.match(ageregex)) {
            ageerror.innerHTML = "Only numbers allowed."
            validage = false;
        }

        verifysubmit();

    }


    function verifysubmit() {

        if (!validage || !validemail || !validpassword || !validusername)
            document.getElementById("signupformsubmit").disabled = true;
        else
            document.getElementById("signupformsubmit").disabled = false;

        console.log(validage + "  " + validemail + "  " + validpassword + "  " + validusername);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: I am calling the functions trough html. (onblur="function()" , onmouseover="function()")

Comment: Try to check work of each check function separately. The mistake may be on regex match function for example or in any condition. Thats why you need to check how every function works.

Comment: If it doesn't help I write you working my own working code for the form verifier that you need.

Comment: Thank you very much , that's very kind ,but I'm actually trying to learn while I develop a website. And I tried what you told me and same result. I actually think that the global variable does not change or something.

Comment: Levente Feher, check my answer again. This code works fine.

Comment: cleaner then mine and worked like a charm.Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107874/discussion-between-levente-feher-and-denismart).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem. Solved link [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/feherlevente/1Lw76qhn/). If you can think of a simpler way to fix this, please comment. Thank you very much for your help.

```
var validemail = false ;
var validpassword = false ;
var validusername = false ;
var validage = false ;


function verifyemail()
{
    var email = document.getElementById("signupemail").value ;
    var error = document.getElementById("signupemailerrors") ;
    var emailregex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/ ;

    if(email.length < 254){
    if( email.length > 0 ){
        if(email.match(emailregex)){
            error.innerHTML = "";
            validemail = true ;
            verifysubmit();
        }
        else
        {
            error.innerHTML = "Invalid email address.";
            validemail = false ;
            verifysubmit();
        }

    }else

    {
        error.innerHTML = "Please fill in." ;
        validemail = false ;
        verifysubmit();
    }
} else
{
    error.innerHTML = "Maximum length exceeded.";
    validemail= false ;
    verifysubmit();
}
}

function verifypassword(){
    var password = document.getElementById("signuppassword").value;
    var passworderror= document.getElementById("signuppassworderrors") ;
    if (password.length < 254){
    if(password.length > 7){
    passworderror.innerHTML = "";
    validpassword = true ;
    verifysubmit();

    }
        else if(password.length == 0)
    {
        passworderror.innerHTML = "Please fill in.";
        validpassword = false ;
        verifysubmit();
    }
    else
    {
        passworderror.innerHTML = "At least 8 characters required.";
        validpassword = false ;
        verifysubmit();
    }
}
    else
    {
        passworderror.innerHTML = "Maximum length exceeded.";
        validpassword = false ;
        verifysubmit();
    }
}

function verifyusername(){
    var username = document.getElementById("signupusername").value ;
    var usernamerror = document.getElementById("signupusernameerrors") ;

    if (username.length == 0)
    {
        usernamerror.innerHTML = "Please fill in.";
        validusername = false;
        verifysubmit();
    }
    else if (username.length > 50)
    {
        usernamerror.innerHTML = "Maximum length exceeded.";
        validusername = false;
        verifysubmit();
    }
    else
    {
        usernamerror.innerHTML = "";
        validusername = true;
        verifysubmit();
    }
}

function verifyage(){
    var age = document.getElementById("signupage").value ;
    var ageerror = document.getElementById("signupageerrors") ;
    var ageregex = /^\d+$/;

    if(age.length == 0){
        ageerror.innerHTML = "Please fill this field";
        validage = false;
        verifysubmit();
    }
    else
    {
    if (age.match(ageregex)){
        if (age == 0){
        ageerror.innerHTML = "Please provide your real age." ;
        validage = false;
        verifysubmit();
        }
        else if(age > 130){
        ageerror.innerHTML = "Please provide your real age." ;
        validage = false;
        verifysubmit();
        }
        else
        {
        ageerror.innerHTML = "" ;
        validage = true;
        verifysubmit();
        }

    }else
    {
        ageerror.innerHTML = "Only numbers allowed."
        validage = false;
        verifysubmit();
    }
}
}


function verifysubmit(){

    if (validage == true && validemail == true && validpassword == true && validusername == true)
    {
     document.getElementById("signupformsubmit").disabled = false ;
    }
else{
    document.getElementById("signupformsubmit").disabled = true ;
}
}
```

Comment: Oh, you faster post this than me edited my answer. Anyway check my answer on the top, it has some better formatting and some shorter code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using "onChange" listener on each field.

`<input type="text" id="signupemail" onchange="verifysubmit()">
    <input type="password" id="signuppassword" onchange="verifysubmit()">
    <input type="text" id="signupusername" onchange="verifysubmit()">
    <input type="text" id="signupage" onchange="verifysubmit()">`

So the onChange will perform the checker on each change and if the checkers are ok you submit button will be re-enabled

Comment: Using "onchange" is bad idea because it works only if focus left. 
Instead of "onchange" is better to use "oninput".

Comment: `oninput`: event occurs when the text content of an element is changed through the user interface.

`onchange`: occurs when the selection, the checked state or the contents of an element have changed. In some cases, it only occurs when the element loses the focus. The onchange attribute can be used with: <input>, <select>, and <textarea>. Tested here with chrome and it works, maybe is a good idea to use both. Just to make sure

Comment: I am calling the functions trough html. (onblur="function()" , onmouseover="function()") But I will try this also seems like a better idea. But the problem is that the function verifysubmit() blocks the submit button if the inputs are wrong but does not re enable when inputs are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a class to all input field which you want to check validation. and for that class you can create on blur method and call verifysubmit() method. "AND I THING YOU HAVE TO RETURN A VALUE WHICH YOU ARE STORING VARIABLE TRUE OR FALSE" store that function out put in variable and check that variable in if condition where you are enable and disable a button.

```
<script>
   $(".errorField").on("blur",function(e){
            verifysubmit();
   })
 </script>
 <input type="text" id="signupemail" class="errorField">
 <input type="password" id="signuppassword" class="errorField">
```

Comment: The function verifysubmit(); is called trough html onmouseover, and it responds because if I don't complete the input fields and I hover the submit button , all the input fields trigger the errors writing  "Please fill this field" and the submit button disables. But when I enter data in the field correctly the submit button does not re enable.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code try it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#signupformsubmit").on("click",function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          verifysubmit();
      });
      $(".errorField").on("blur",function(e){
        verifysubmit();
      })
      var validemail = false ;
      var validpassword = false ;
      var validusername = false ;
      var validage = false ;

      function verifyemail()
    {
      var email = document.getElementById("signupemail").value ;
      var error = document.getElementById("signupemailerrors") ;
      var emailregex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/ ;

      if(email.length < 254){
      if( email.length > 0 ){
          if(email.match(emailregex)){
              error.innerHTML = "";
              console.log("preg");
              return validemail = true ;
          }
          else
          {
              error.innerHTML = "Invalid email address.";
              return validemail = false ;
          }

      }else

      {
          error.innerHTML = "Please fill in." ;
          return validemail = false ;
      }
    } else
    {
      error.innerHTML = "Maximum length exceeded.";
      return validemail= false ;
    }
    }

    function verifypassword(){
      var password = document.getElementById("signuppassword").value;
      var passworderror= document.getElementById("signuppassworderrors") ;
      if (password.length < 254){
      if(password.length > 7){
      passworderror.innerHTML = "";
      return validpassword = true ;

      }
          else if(password.length == 0)
      {
          passworderror.innerHTML = "Please fill in.";
          return validpassword = false ;
      }
      else
      {
          passworderror.innerHTML = "At least 8 characters required.";
          return validpassword = false ;
      }
    }
      else
      {
          passworderror.innerHTML = "Maximum length exceeded.";
          return validpassword = false ;
      }
    }

    function verifyusername(){
      var username = document.getElementById("signupusername").value ;
      var usernamerror = document.getElementById("signupusernameerrors") ;

      if (username.length == 0)
      {
          usernamerror.innerHTML = "Please fill in.";
          validusername = false;
      }
      else if (username.length > 50)
      {
          usernamerror.innerHTML = "Maximum length exceeded.";
          validusername = false;
      }
      else
      {
          usernamerror.innerHTML = "";
          validusername = true;
      }
    }

    function verifyage(){
      var age = document.getElementById("signupage").value ;
      var ageerror = document.getElementById("signupageerrors") ;
      var ageregex = /^\d+$/;

      if(age.length == 0){
          ageerror.innerHTML = "Please fill this field";
          validage = false;
      }
      else
      {
      if (age.match(ageregex)){
          if (age == 0){
          ageerror.innerHTML = "Please provide your real age." ;
          validage = false;
          }
          else if(age > 130){
          ageerror.innerHTML = "Please provide your real age." ;
          validage = false;
          }
          else
          {
          ageerror.innerHTML = "" ;
          validage = true;
          }

      }else
      {
          ageerror.innerHTML = "Only numbers allowed."
          validage = false;
      }
    }
    }


    function verifysubmit(){
      console.log("test");
      //verifyage();
      var email = verifyemail();
       var pass = verifypassword();
       console.log(email+pass);
      // verifyusername();
      if (email == 1 && pass == 1)
      {
        console.log("true");
       document.getElementById("signupformsubmit").disabled = false ;
      }
    else{
      document.getElementById("signupformsubmit").disabled = true ;
    }
    }
    });
    </script>
    <input type="text" id="signupemail" class="errorField">
    <input type="password" id="signuppassword" class="errorField">
    <input type="button" id="signupformsubmit" value="Submit" >
    <div id="signupemailerrors"></div>
    <div id="signuppassworderrors"></div>

    </html>
```

Comment: i don't see a form tag in the answer